# PHP text going missing, possible regex issue?

Tags: php

I'm attempting to create an automatic installer for a system I have created, but the ONLY issue is the generation of a php file, in which variables simply do not show up.

Here's my code to create the file

```
<?php
$content = " <?php
    $sqlHost = '".$host."';
    $sqlUser = '".$user."';
    $sqlPass = '".$pass."';
    $sqlDatabase = '".$db."';
    $sqlTables = array('donate_categories', 'donate_items', 'donate_claim', 'donate_admin');

    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$sqlHost.';dbname='.$sqlDatabase.';charset-utf8', $sqlUser, $sqlPass);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>";

$fp = fopen("connection.php", "wb");
fwrite($fp, $content);
$fclose($fp);
?>
```

as you can see there's php code wrapped in a string there; However the output is a little strange...

```
<?php
     = 'localhost';
     = 'root';
     = '';
     = 'test';
     = array('donate_categories', 'donate_items', 'donate_claim', 'donate_admin');

     = new PDO('mysql:host='..';dbname='..';charset-utf8', , );
    (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

None of the variables are there, and I've looked up possible issues with this, but I haven't found any.

Comment: Try `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Double quotes interpolate variables.

Comment: The problem itself can be easily fixed by escaping the `$` symbols (or switching the double quotes to single quotes), but _why_ would you want to do this? What exactly is the point of using PHP code generate more PHP code?

Comment: This seems like a good use case for a heredoc rather than this confusing concatenation. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc  The `$connection` would still need `\$` escaping though.

Comment: @NullUserException  I would assume, like a lot of systems that have a setup/install page, to create the corresponding `config.php` file.

Comment: Just a thought: it would probably be cleaner to generate a `ini` or `yaml` file.

Comment: @Dagon It's not a duplicate. That question is for displaying PHP on a web page. This question is about writing it to a file. The solutions are different. The problem he has here is actually with quoting.

Answer (score 4):

I can't test this right now, but since you've wrapped the text in double quotes, your server is parsing the variables `$sqlHost, $sqlUser, ...` etc as variables and looking up their values in the string. Try escaping the values like so, and let me know if it works as you intend it to.

```
<?php
$content = " <?php
    \$sqlHost = '".$host."';
    \$sqlUser = '".$user."';
    \$sqlPass = '".$pass."';
    \$sqlDatabase = '".$db."';
    \$sqlTables = array('donate_categories', 'donate_items', 'donate_claim', 'donate_admin');

    \$connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.\$sqlHost.';dbname='.\$sqlDatabase.';charset-utf8', \$sqlUser, \$sqlPass);
   \$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>";

$fp = fopen("connection.php", "wb");
fwrite($fp, $content);
$fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works; Could you provide a link to more information on the different between using `'string'` and `"string"`.. I had no idea that `"string"` would parse variables, does `'string'` not?

Comment: The manual is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: @Christian.tucker That is explained in the strings doc I linked up in the main comment thread

Comment: Null User beat me to it, that link should have all the information you need. And to answer your question, no, strings encapsulated in single quotes such as '$string' would not parse variables, but "$string" would. I *believe* (been awhile since I thumbed through the INI specs) there's an option you can turn on/off, but it could be totally deprecated by now.

Comment: @Christian.tucker: You are writing an installer script for a system you created … without even knowing such absolute basics? Wow … installing your system might turn out “interesting” for whoever uses it.

Comment: @CBroe - Thanks for the information ;) However the quoting here was the only issue and everything works perfectly now. File generation, database population, etc.   Thanks for your concern though ;) `Syntax and logic are different things.`

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes, because it is trying to replace the variables into the string.

```
<?php
$content = ' <?php
    $sqlHost = "'.$host.'";
    $sqlUser = "'.$user.'";
    $sqlPass = "'.$pass.'";
    $sqlDatabase = "'.$db.'";
    $sqlTables = array("donate_categories", "donate_items", "donate_claim", "donate_admin");

    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$sqlHost.";dbname=".$sqlDatabase.";charset-utf8", $sqlUser, $sqlPass);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>';

$fp = fopen('connection.php', 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $content);
$fclose($fp);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php

Regards.